# Проблема с командой для бота на discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

В общем я пишу бота и столкнулся с довольно страной проблемой. Я написал команду, которая выводит аватар выбранного пользователя в Embed сообщении

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Avatar(ctx, *member: discord.Member):
    if member:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title = "Аватар участника " + member.name, color = 0x9932cc)
        embedVar.set_image(url = member.avatar)
    else:
        user = ctx.message.author
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title = "Аватар участника " + ctx.author.name, color = 0x9932cc)
        embedVar.set_image(url = user.avatar)
    await ctx.send(embed = embedVar)
```

В этой команде можно указать пользователя, но это не обязательно. Если этого не делать, то команда выводит аватар автора сообщения. Если указать пользователя, то соответственно выведет его аватар. Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать эту команду с указанием пользователя - мне говорят что в кортеже member нет элемента name.

```
  File "c:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\AbsoluteSolver\bot.py", line 78, in Avatar
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title = "Аватар участника " + member.name, color = 0x9932cc)
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
```

При этом если я из кода убираю звезду(которая делает аргумент не обязательным), то ошибка исчезает, но, понятное дело, команда не будет работать без аргументов. Мне бы хотелось что бы работало и то, и другое. Я пробовал так же поменять в списке аргументов Member на User, но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. в определение вашей функции не `member`, а `*member`, то значение переменной `member` будет кортеж с одним элементом.

Примените команду (запятая в ней важнa)

```
member, = member
```

после `if`, чтобы в переменной `member` получить сам объект (типа `discord.Member`) т.е.

```
if member:
    member, = member
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title = "Аватар участника " + member.name, color = 0x9932cc)
    embedVar.set_image(url = member.avatar)
```